# Rail 3 Custom Environment Variables

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1

How do we create custom environment variables in Rails 3.1?

For example, in my mailer I might want to send an email from emailA@domain.com during development mode but I want to send an email from emailB@domain.com during production.

I tried something like [this](http://jasonnoble.org/2011/02/rails3-custom-environment-variables.html) but got an error saying the variable was not initialized.

Thanks :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your environment files, add a variable

**app/config/environments/development.rb**

```
YourApp::Application.configure do
  # other stuff... 
  config.admin_email = "admin_development@gmail.com"
end
```

**app/config/environments/production.rb**

```
YourApp::Application.configure do
  # other stuff... 
  config.admin_email = "admin_production@gmail.com"
end
```

Depending on the environment, `YourApp::Application.config.admin_email` will contain either `admin_development@gmail.com` or `admin_production@gmail.com`

**Alternatively**, if the emails only differ by the environment name, I would suggest doing something like this...

```
admin_email = "admin_#{Rails.env}@gmail.com"
```